# jquery move through list of elements adding and remove class in sequence

Tags: jquery, class, timeout, sequence

can't quite nail down my logic for this one: been a long day. Essentially I have a list of images that I need to run through on repeat adding a class to each for a set amount of time and clearing the class each time.

so that's:

add class, timeout, remove class, repeat for next and if last go to the first

here's what I've got, it's not working at all:

```
ul.find('.frame').each(function(){

    var thiis = $(this);

    thiis.addClass('showing');

    setTimeout(function(){
        thiis.removeClass('showing');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: because you have added it inside of `each` loop.

Comment: @DipeshParmar does that somehow null the timeout? do you have a recommendation for an alternate technique or any documentation on why it won't work?

Comment: @ahren clearly i do not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $f = $('ul').find('.frame');

function recursive(i) {
    $f.removeClass('showing').eq(i).addClass('showing');
    setTimeout(function () {
        recursive(++i % $f.length)
    }, 1000);
}
recursive(0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wja4r/

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `setInterval` - which repeats until you clear it.

```
var $items = $('.frame'),
    delay = 1000;
    $items.first().addClass('showing');

setInterval(function(){
  var $current = $items.filter('.showing'),
      $next = $current.next().length ? $current.next() : $items.first();

  $current.removeClass('showing');
  $next.addClass('showing');
}, delay);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/PELjq/2/